# Howto copy README.md into src/main/resources?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-resources-plugin

I want to show `README.md` file like help page in my web application. In order not to create duplicate, I need to copy by `mvn` from project path into resources.

How can I do so?

Any idea?

I have tried:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>

    <configuration>
        <!-- this is important -->
        <overwrite>true</overwrite>
        <!-- target -->
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <!-- source -->
                <directory>/</directory>
                <include>
                    <filter>**/README.md</filter>
                </include>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Just putting them in your resources folder is not an option?

Comment: `<directory>/</directory>` is suspicious, try with `<directory>${basedir}</directory>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to move the appropriate file(s) to `src/main/resources` folder whereas the second solution could be like this:

```xml
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>README.md</include>
        </includes>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>
```

No need for [maven-resources-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) to be configured this can be handled by the usual life cylcle and resource handling. The only thing you might need to adapt is the folder where the `README.md` is located. If you like having filtering you need to add the `<filtering>true</filtering>` part as well.

Copying something via Maven during the build into `src/**` is in general a bad idea, cause those folders are controled by version control systems which will result in uncommitted changes which you don't like to have.

Note: It would be wise to check for up-to-date versions of plugins (cause 2.3 is of 2008!). The list of the current plugin versions can be found here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Comment: current sould be 2.7 i guess ;)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in one of my projects:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <!-- when to execute copy operation -->
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/pathTo.MD</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/classes</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I see that i have the phase and the goal extra from your version. I also used variables for the output location.

Comment: Thank you, I prefer @khmarbaise solution

Comment: I used it like this cause i only copy that resources based on some profiles.

Comment: I see. In my case, I need to copy it always. Thanks for explanation

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to be more equal to this example: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html 
With "more equal" I mean like using `<executions>` tag.

You can of course leave out things like `<id>` and `filtering`.

The following worked fine for me:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>myID</id>
            <!-- here the phase you need -->
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/extra-resources</outputDirectory>
              <overwrite>true</overwrite>
              <resources>          
                <resource>
                  <directory>src</directory>
                  <!-- Details about filtering: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html -->
                  <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
              </resources>              
            </configuration>            
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```